# When using relative values to repeatedly move an object with jQuery's animate() function, can you set a max value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
$("#container").animate({"top": "-=276px"}, "slow");
```

I would love to know if I can set a max value easily somehow within this function, so people cannot just infinite scroll my container up. I've searched in a number of places, but only found solutions suggesting using additional functions and variables. is there really no way to do something like... -=276px<5520, where 5520 is the max value?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. I was thinking you could use one of the `max-` CSS properties, but they only support `width` and `height`. Check out [this link](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=max) for more info on that, and other properties you could use...

Like you said, you've already explored using additional functions, but for the sake of thoroughness, I might attempt it like this:

```
var max_top_value = 5520;
var new_top_value = parseInt($("#container").css("top")) + 276;

new_top_value = (new_top_value > 5520 ? 5520 : new_top_value);
$("#container").animate({"top": new_top_value + "px"}, "slow");
```

Not exactly what you were hoping for, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the attempt Chris. This works, but like I said I'm looking for a simpler way to do this. it's going within a very JS heavy page, so less is more. but either way appreciate the breakdown and example. thank you!

Comment: Why is the page so JS heavy, and how would something like that push it over the top when the calculation would need to be made implicitly anyway? But coolness, sorry I couldn't be more helpful!